# Swagger API Inspector - Blocked by Network

Tags: swagger

I try to generate API contracts from existing endpoints. The issue is our company network blocking Swagger API Inspector and the extension to chrome is also blocked. IS there any way to install swagger API inspector through NodeJS. Thanks in advance.